# Is Cyanogenmod available for a Trio Stealth G2 10.1"?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I recently purchased a cheaper tablet and would like to put Cyanogenmod on it. I've done some Googling over the past couple of days, but have been unable to find any information for my specific tablet.

Is there a ROM for a similar device that I can try flashing? Or, better yet, has anyone been able to get Cyanogenmod working on a Trio Stealth G2 10.1"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the list of [officially](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices) supported and [unofficially](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Unofficial_Ports) ported devices, **no**.

Also, read more at [this](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/72612-can-i-get-cyanogenmod-on-my-device/) sticky post by CyanogenMod moderators.